# Sorting String Array by Last Name from a File

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a .txt file which contains pairs FirstName LastName, like this:

- Sam Foster
- Jack White
- John Abner
- Mike Briggs
- Sarah Mills

(No bullets, of course) The delimiter is space. Task is to sort this file, in java, by last names, so it looks like this:

- John Abner
- Mike Briggs
- Sam Foster
- Sarah Mills
- Jack White

I've searched and searched, but found no explanation I can understand. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: In what **LANGUAGE** do you whish to accomplish this?

Comment: in java, sorry about that

Comment: @anubhava only if you write your own Comparator; Lexical sorting doesn't know about last names ;)

Comment: The tutorials from Oracle cover this nicely: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no middle name and there is no suffix like `Jr` in the end.

#### Read file into a list:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filepath"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext())
    list.add(s.next());
s.close();
```

#### Define a custom comparator:

```
static class LastNameComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String b1, String b2) {
        String[] arr1 = b1.split(" ");
        String[] arr2 = b2.split(" ");
        if (arr1.length > 1 && arr2.length > 1)
            return arr1[arr1.length-1].compareTo(arr2[arr2.length-1]);
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

#### Sort the list using custom comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, new LastNameComparator());
```

#### Write it back to file:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("outFile.txt"); 
for(String str: list) {
  writer.write(str);
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: -1 for what? Did I not get the question right?

Comment: Sorry. Will withdraw my downvote when the answer is fixed? "Task is to sort this file, in java, by last names"

Comment: Alright I will edit my answer.

Comment: @fiction: I overlooked initially about sort on Last Name requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a Comparator which get the second word in your String and compare them.

```
public class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String b1, String b2) {
      return b1.split(" ")[1].compareTo(b2.split(" ")[1]);
  }
}
```

then you can use `Arrays.sort(array, new StringComparator());`